# neo4j number between two numbers

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have these three nodes in my graph connected to a node `:Card`

```
( silver:Level {points:500,  pointsToWin:20} )

( gold:Level   {points:1000, pointsToWin:30} )

( casual:Level {points:0,    pointsToWin:10} )
```

In the case that I had matched the `lvlPoints` of the user and I have it in the actual query in `h.lvlPoints`

How can I know how many points the user has to retrieve (`pointsToWin`) when I realise the query?

```
MATCH (u:Person)
WHERE u.name = "Jhon"
MATCH (c:Company)
WHERE c.name = "Some Company"

MATCH (u)-[h:HAS_CARD]->(card:Card)-[:IS_FROM]->(c)
MATCH (card)-[:HAS_LEVEL]->(lvl:Level)

// Now check for this ->  somelvl.points < h.lvlPoints < otherlvl.points
```

I know that I can return the values and then in the client or the server make the necessary operations for this, but I am looking for a cypher solution, if it is possible

EDIT: In my case
 - There are more levels in the graph with the same points value but with other value on pointsToWin or not connected to the same `:Card`
 - In the case you have 300 points, you are a casual level, because you have more than 0 points but less than 500 points (silver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have something that works, just wanted to offer an alternative.

You should be able to use matches and predicates, and a quick use of ordering and limiting the result to get the levels you want, without needing to use CASE at all.

```
MATCH (u:Person)
WHERE u.name = "Jhon"
MATCH (c:Company)
WHERE c.name = "Some Company"

MATCH (u)-[h:HAS_CARD]->(card:Card)-[:IS_FROM]->(c)
MATCH (card)-[:HAS_LEVEL]->(lvl:Level)

// above is directly from your description
// below should return, for the highest qualified level, its pointsToWin

WHERE lvl.points <= h.lvlPoints
WITH u, lvl
ORDER BY lvl.points DESC
LIMIT 1
RETURN u, lvl.pointsToWin
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your solution and your time ! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the generic version of the [`CASE` expression](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/expressions/#syntax-generic-case):

```
CASE
  WHEN predicate THEN result
  [WHEN ...]
  [ELSE default]
END
```

So you can write something like

```
// ...
CASE
  WHEN h.lvlPoints < 500  THEN "casual"
  WHEN h.lvlPoints < 1000 THEN "silver"
  ELSE                         "gold"
END
```

For you scenario, a better approach might be to convert the number to the required minimum:

```
// get u and h
// ...
WITH u, h, CASE
    WHEN h.lvlPoints < 500  THEN 0
    WHEN h.lvlPoints < 1000 THEN 500
  ELSE                           1000
END AS levelMinimumPoints
MATCH (level:Level {points: levelMinimumPoints})
RETURN u, level.pointsToWin
```

*Update:* if the `points` values are dynamic, you can use an approach like this:

```
// get u and h
// ...
MATCH (level:Level)
WITH u, h, level
ORDER BY level.points
WITH u, h, collect(level.points) AS points, collect(level.pointsToWin) AS pointsToWin
WITH
  u, CASE
    WHEN h.lvlPoints < points[1] THEN pointsToWin[0]
    WHEN h.lvlPoints < points[2] THEN pointsToWin[1]
    ELSE                              pointsToWin[2]
  END AS pointsEarned
RETURN u, pointsEarned
```

For a more generic case, if you can have an arbitrary amount of levels, you should replace `CASE` with something else. For example, you can [`filter`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#functions-filter) for values in the list that are small than or equal to the lvlPoints - and then take the last value. It should look something like this:

```
// ...
WITH filter(x IN points WHERE x <= h.lvlPoints) AS largerPoints
WITH largerPoints[length(largerPoints)-1] AS levelMinimumPoints
MATCH (level:Level {points: levelMinimumPoints})
// ...
```

Comment: Okay, this is great, but .. I can't write the literals 500, 1000 because this numbers can be modified and they are defined in the :Level nodes from the card :S 
I think you are in the correct way, but i need something like 
   WHEN h.lvlPoints < X THEN before(X)

PD: Probably in the server I can make first a cypher query to find the values and then make the next query writing the values on your way, but in this case I need to do all in one query.

Comment: @YuniorGlez I updated my answer - check if it fits your use case.

Comment: Yeahhh ^^ a lot of thanks, but ... if ... the number of Levels it is not forever three for example ? If one card could have three lvls but another can have only two ? Sorry :S But in this cases is like this.

Comment: I tested the prev solution for static cases of points and it's works perfectly but when yo find h.lvlPoints < points[1] you have to return THEN points[0] and so I write the cases as points[1] THEN points[0] and points[2] THEN points[1] and its works.

But, the filter solution, doesn't work due to the same thing, because when you have 300pts, you are in the casual lvl, because you don't have 500 points yet, this is (I think) the difficulty of the query. If I use filter I return the next level that the user is near to unlock

Comment: Well, you can keep only the values in the list that are <= to the lvlPoints and then take the last value. See my updated solution.

Comment: Both solutions work perfectly ^^ I have to remove the `MATCH` at the end because the points variable is not a constraint unique.
I pass the level node in the `WITH` statements across the query and at the end I added `WHERE level.points = levelMinimumPoints` and it's works :) Well, thanks for all Gabor !